# SitckyListHeader with Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, parallax, sticky

I use Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager library
and I will like to use this library to manage my ListView:
https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

Everything works but the headers of the stickyListHeader are masked by the header of viewpager ...
I do not see how to "force" the headers of the Listview to stay below the viewpager / tabhost.

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ScrollTabHolder, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private static AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator sSmoothInterpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();

    private KenBurnsSupportView mHeaderPicture;
    private View mHeader;

    private PagerSlidingTabStrip mPagerSlidingTabStrip;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    private int mActionBarHeight;
    private int mMinHeaderHeight;
    private int mHeaderHeight;
    private int mMinHeaderTranslation;
    private int mSizeImageHeader;
    private ImageView mHeaderLogo;

    private RectF mRect1 = new RectF();
    private RectF mRect2 = new RectF();

    private TypedValue mTypedValue = new TypedValue();
    private SpannableString mSpannableString;
    private AlphaForegroundColorSpan mAlphaForegroundColorSpan;

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TextView title;
    private ImageView icon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMinHeaderHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.min_header_height);
        mHeaderHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.header_height);
        mMinHeaderTranslation = -mMinHeaderHeight + getActionBarHeight();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

        mHeaderPicture = (KenBurnsSupportView) findViewById(R.id.header_picture);
        mHeaderPicture.setResourceIds(R.drawable.couverture2, R.drawable.couverture);
        mHeaderLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header_logo);
        setFacebookImage();
        mHeader = findViewById(R.id.header);

        mPagerSlidingTabStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

        mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPagerAdapter.setTabHolderScrollingContent(this);

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

        mPagerSlidingTabStrip.setViewPager(mViewPager);
        mPagerSlidingTabStrip.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        mSpannableString = new SpannableString(getString(R.string.app_name));
        mAlphaForegroundColorSpan = new AlphaForegroundColorSpan(0xffffffff);

        ViewHelper.setAlpha(getActionBarIconView(), 0f);

        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        // nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        // nothing
    }

    public int getPixelsFromDip(int dip, Context context) {
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dip, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    public void setFacebookImage(){
        mSizeImageHeader = getPixelsFromDip(44, this.getApplicationContext());
        //TODO Recuperer image FB
        Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.photo_profil)
                .resize(mSizeImageHeader, mSizeImageHeader)
                .transform(new RoundedTransformation(mSizeImageHeader, 0))
                .into(mHeaderLogo);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        SparseArrayCompat<ScrollTabHolder> scrollTabHolders = mPagerAdapter.getScrollTabHolders();
        ScrollTabHolder currentHolder = scrollTabHolders.valueAt(position);

        currentHolder.adjustScroll((int) (mHeader.getHeight() + ViewHelper.getTranslationY(mHeader)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount, int pagePosition) {
        if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == pagePosition) {
            int scrollY = getScrollY(view);
            ViewHelper.setTranslationY(mHeader, Math.max(-scrollY, mMinHeaderTranslation));
            float ratio = clamp(ViewHelper.getTranslationY(mHeader) / mMinHeaderTranslation, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            interpolate(mHeaderLogo, getActionBarIconView(), sSmoothInterpolator.getInterpolation(ratio));
            setTitleAlpha(clamp(5.0F * ratio - 4.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void adjustScroll(int scrollHeight) {
        // nothing
    }

    public int getScrollY(AbsListView view) {
        View c = view.getChildAt(0);
        if (c == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        int firstVisiblePosition = view.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        int top = c.getTop();

        int headerHeight = 0;
        if (firstVisiblePosition >= 1) {
            headerHeight = mHeaderHeight;
        }

        return -top + firstVisiblePosition * c.getHeight() + headerHeight;
    }

    public static float clamp(float value, float max, float min) {
        return Math.max(Math.min(value, min), max);
    }

    private void interpolate(View view1, View view2, float interpolation) {
        getOnScreenRect(mRect1, view1);
        getOnScreenRect(mRect2, view2);

        float scaleX = 1.0F + interpolation * (mRect2.width() / mRect1.width() - 1.0F);
        float scaleY = 1.0F + interpolation * (mRect2.height() / mRect1.height() - 1.0F);
        float translationX = 0.5F * (interpolation * (mRect2.left + mRect2.right - mRect1.left - mRect1.right));
        float translationY = 0.5F * (interpolation * (mRect2.top + mRect2.bottom - mRect1.top - mRect1.bottom));

        ViewHelper.setTranslationX(view1, translationX);
        ViewHelper.setTranslationY(view1, translationY - ViewHelper.getTranslationY(mHeader));
        ViewHelper.setScaleX(view1, scaleX);
        ViewHelper.setScaleY(view1, scaleY);
    }

    private RectF getOnScreenRect(RectF rect, View view) {
        rect.set(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom());
        return rect;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public int getActionBarHeight() {
        if (mActionBarHeight != 0) {
            return mActionBarHeight;
        }

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
            getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, mTypedValue, true);
        }else{
            getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.actionBarSize, mTypedValue, true);
        }

        mActionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(mTypedValue.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        return mActionBarHeight;
    }

    private void setTitleAlpha(float alpha) {
        mAlphaForegroundColorSpan.setAlpha(alpha);
        mSpannableString.setSpan(mAlphaForegroundColorSpan, 0, mSpannableString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        title.setText(mSpannableString);
    }

    private ImageView getActionBarIconView() {
        return icon;
    }

    public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private SparseArrayCompat<ScrollTabHolder> mScrollTabHolders;
        private final String[] TITLES = { "Accueil", "Nouvel Evenement"};
        private ScrollTabHolder mListener;

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            mScrollTabHolders = new SparseArrayCompat<ScrollTabHolder>();
        }

        public void setTabHolderScrollingContent(ScrollTabHolder listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return TITLES[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TITLES.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            ScrollTabHolderFragment fragment;

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = (ScrollTabHolderFragment) AccueilFragment.newInstance(position);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    fragment = (ScrollTabHolderFragment) NewEventFragment.newInstance(position);
                    break;
                default:
                    return null;

            }

            mScrollTabHolders.put(position, fragment);
            if (mListener != null) {
                fragment.setScrollTabHolder(mListener);
            }

            return fragment;
        }

        public SparseArrayCompat<ScrollTabHolder> getScrollTabHolders() {
            return mScrollTabHolders;
        }

    }
}
```

AcceuilFragment (class use StickylistHeader) :

```
public class AccueilFragment extends ScrollTabHolderFragment implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {

    StickyListHeadersListView listEvent;
    ListEventAdapter listAdapter;
    ArrayList<Evenement> evenements;
    private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";


    View header;
    RoundedImageView avatar;
    private View placeHolderView;

    private int mPosition;

    public static android.support.v4.app.Fragment newInstance(int position) {
        AccueilFragment f = new AccueilFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_accueil, null);

        //headerList = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);
        placeHolderView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_header_placeholder, listEvent, false);

        return mainView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mPosition = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);

        // get the listview
        listEvent = (StickyListHeadersListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listEvent);
        avatar = (RoundedImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        header = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.header);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ListEventAdapter(getActivity(), evenements);



        // setting list adapter
        listEvent.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listEvent.setOnScrollListener(this);
        listEvent.addHeaderView(placeHolderView);

        //listEvent.addHeaderView(headerList);

    }

    private void prepareListData() {

        evenements = new ArrayList<Evenement>();

        //populate evenements



    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    private boolean listIsAtTop()   {
        if(listEvent.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0 && (listEvent.getChildCount() == 0 || listEvent.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static void setMargins (View v, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        if (v.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            p.setMargins(l, t, r, b);
            v.requestLayout();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void adjustScroll(int scrollHeight) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (mScrollTabHolder != null)
            mScrollTabHolder.onScroll(view, firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount, mPosition);
    }


}
```

Comment: Hey have you got any solution for this problem? I am also facing similar kind of problem.

Comment: No sorry, I have changed my UI Interface ..